# Image displays until it's wrapped by {figure}

Tags: graphics

I have the following code which works and adds an image to my document

```
 \includegraphics[scale=0.71]{ed.jpg}
```

However when I try to turn it into a figure

```
 \begin{figure}[t]
 \caption{A nice picture.}
 \centering
 \includegraphics[scale=0.71]{ed.jpg}
 \end{figure}
```

The image disappears.

I'm using the following packages

```
 \usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
 \usepackage{float}
```

Can anyone point out my mistake? I'm sure it's fairly obvious but it's been winding me up for days. The Latex compiler isn't producing any error messages.

Comment: Are there any warnings?

Comment: Nope, no warnings.. also it compiles fine when not wrapped in figure tags

Comment: Option `draft` enabled somewhere? The caption is displayed? MWE?

Comment: Are you sure that it disappears? It may go to the next page.

Comment: Yes, deffinatly disapered. No, draft not enabled. 

Cheers for the help so far.

Comment: @ChrisHeadleand It's *really* very likely that you have some error listed in the `.log` file. What are you using for compiling the file?

Answer (score 2):

`pdftex` option for `graphicx` package have to be omitted.

```
\documentclass{article}‎

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}‎‎

\begin{figure}[t]
\caption{A nice picture.}
\centering‎
\includegraphics[scale=0.71]{ed.jpg}
\end{figure}‎

\end{document}
```

Comment: Just tried that... no difference I'm afraid :(

Comment: I can run it without any problem. How do you compile your code? Is there any error or warning? Is there your image, in the current folder?

Comment: yeah, without the figure it compiles fine. I'm compiling my code with pdflatex and with latex. its just wrapping it in figure tags that causes the problem, no warnings.

Comment: MWE and output, please